# Applying CultureInfo.InvariantCulture to a string

Tags: c#, string, cultureinfo

Basically I am formatting a string so that it has a specific set of 0's and is done so like the following for any data type that is NOT already a string:

```
string weight = Convert.ToDouble(item.Weight).ToString("00000.000",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Replace(".", "");
```

Where item.Weight is a string value.

However I want to do this without double handling by converting to a double then back to a string just so I can use CultureInfo.InvariantCulture with the ToString method?
Is there another way I can do this? As I cannot call a ToString on a string.

Thanks in advance

Comment: [String.ToString()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/29dxe1x2%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) does not allow to format numbers, so the conversion to a double is necessary.

Comment: You could try [String.Format()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx) method

Answer (score -1):

This should do: Convert.ToDouble(item.Weight).ToString("#.##0")